# Connection to capitol without port

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I have a capitol that doesn't have an exit to the sea but it is connected to another city with a harbor. My other cities are blocked by a non-friendly city state (connected via a road that passes through that city) but there is one other city with a harbor.

Should I have a connection to the other group of cities?  In this situation, I did not, as my cities were disconnected when I stopped being friends with the previously mentioned city state.

[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't you?  There's still a connection to your other cities through your harbors.  Rather than taking roads, it just has to sail around most of the world.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the requirements for harbors to connect to your trade route?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190914/what-are-the-requirements-for-harbors-to-connect-to-your-trade-route)

Comment: @Schism - This question is NOT the dupe. Look at the date it was asked. The other question is the dupe.

Comment: @5pike Date is not relevant in determining whether a question is a dupe. [The community agrees that "It's nice to prioritize older questions, but it's a secondary concern. If a newer one does the same thing better, then the older one should be closed to point to it."](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7284/what-is-the-policy-on-older-questions-rendered-obsolete-by-newer-ones#comment20195_7284) Since this question is a specific case, while the other question is a generalised version, it would appear the other one is superior and obsoletes this one.

Comment: @Schism - Oh, I see. Did not know that. Thanks!

Comment: @Schism and 5pike: The current top-voted answer in this more recent meta post: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8188/on-ending-chronological-oppression-with-respect-to-the-matter-of-question-duplic - suggests that the question which has the first definitively upvoted answer (2+ votes) should be the "master" question.

Comment: @galacticninja +8/-5 hardly looks to me like community consensus so I'd be wary of taking that advice for fact. (Granted, linking to a +15 comment doesn't show any dissent, but it still has more support.) Also, the case in that question was dealing with two questions that had been up a similar amount of time (like < 24 hrs difference) and thus a similar amount of attention / opportunity to be upvoted, which is not the case here; this has 73.7 views / vote (51 on the answer), while the other has 28.5 v/v (16.3 on the answer). I know this is a sketchy metric, but it's a metric nonetheless.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the map, it looks like your water route goes north from the city near your capitol, around the northwest peninsula, then hugging the west coastline, swinging around the city-state at the southwest peninsula, and then into your other harbor.

The trouble is that you haven't explored a sea route through uncontrolled areas. Your "invisible trade ships" aren't willing to go into unexplored water to connect your empire together, and aren't able to go through territory that belongs to someone else. Looking at the map, the city-states in the northwest and southwest of your known territory might cut off the straight-water-route between your two harbored cities; the gray civilization (Germans?) to the west of your capitol might also be a problem, if they own all of the water tiles you might go through. You either need to make nice with those two city-states and the gray civilization, or invent Astronomy and expand your knowledge of the Ocean tiles with a Caravel so that your trade can route around the hexes claimed by the blocking city-states and civilization.

Alternatively, you can found a city just east of the labeled city-state in your map, on the water, and put a harbor there. Then your "invisible trade ships" just need to cross a short bay instead of navigating the long way around the continent. (This will depend on whether the city-states to the south and southeast of your capitol own all of the sea hexes on the south end of that bay. You may need to buy a couple of sea hexes quickly to make sure the city-states don't block your access later.)