# How can I send multiple caravans/cargo ships to feed a single city in Civ 5?

Tags: civilization-5

I can feed a city, A, by sending a caravan to A, from B.
I can feed A even more by sending a cargo ship to A, from C.

If I select a caravan or cargo ship from D, A is not on the list of destinations.

Is this a bug, or part of the game?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190914/what-are-the-requirements-for-harbors-to-connect-to-your-trade-route

Answer (score 2):

In order of likelihood:

It may be out of range of either the Caravan or Cargo Ship from D.

An enemy may have blockaded the available paths between A and D with their military units (more likely for a land route with just one road from A to D, less likely for sea routes unless there is an enemy vessel particularly near either city).

Your civilization may have all its trade slots full (although if this is the case, typically you wouldn't have been able to construct the Caravan or Cargo Ship in the first place, so this is not likely your problem).

Comment: Each city has a trade capacity?  I'm not saying I don't believe you, but where might I find that in the game, the counter or display for it?

Comment: It's possible I'm mis-remembering, because the Civ games run together in my head a little bit, but I'm pretty sure they do.  I'll double-check.

Comment: @user2738698 Sorry, you're right, in V it's a per-civ trade route limit (which is almost certainly not your problem, since you were allowed to build the Caravan or Cargo Ship to begin with).

Answer (score 1):

D is most likely too far away from A, you'll need some building which increases the distance a caravan can travel. There is neither a limit in how many caravans you can send from one city nor a limit in how many caravans a city can receive.